# Fire back event twice in single click. Android

Tags: android, back

I want to fire back event twice in single click of the back button in Android. How will be this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Run the event twice in the overridden on click method

```
Button mClickButton1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clickButton1);
mClickButton1.setOnClickListener(this);

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     event();
     event();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you click on back button it will call method below:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
     super.onBackPressed();
}
```

and this method will be call super.onBackPressed(); that this will call application to finished and quit it.

if you need to call some methods when you press back button twice you should implement a counter for press like method below:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (backPressedTime == '') {
        backPressedTime = t;
        counter = 1;
    } 
    else if (t - backPressedTime > 2000) { // 2 secs
         counter = 0;
         backPressedTime = t;
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.retry_to_exit,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 
    else 
    { 
      counter++;
      if(counter > 2)
      {
      }
      else
      {
         // this guy is serious
         // clean up
         super.onBackPressed(); // bye
         finish();
      }
    }

}
```

and at the end if you need to call some methods in backpress events you can add your method to

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
     yourEvent();
     yourEvent();
     super.onBackPressed();
}
```

if you need to run in different thread you can call

```
    new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            yourMethod()
        }
    };
```

and if you need to call methods with some delay you can use

```
                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            tourMethod();
                        }
                    }, 2000);
```